# Rendering labels outside of GitLab Markdown

Tags: gitlab

In GitLab Markdown, labels, such as `~Bug` are rendered like bootstrap pill buttons with their custom colours.

Is there a way to use the API or similar to generate HTML representations of labels for a project? For example, to nicely render the docs of a project in GitLab Pages?

Answer (score 1):

The GitLab Markdown "[Special GitLab references](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#special-gitlab-references)" does include 'project name' as "`namespace/project`".

But:

- they are not rendered as labels
- they are only links, and not for cross-project files ([issue 30204](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/30204))

So I doubt there is an API doing what GitLab Markdown itself does not.